# V8 doesn't optimize function after 'manually' doing typed array .set()s

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, optimization, v8

I have the following function (I'm posting it entirely because all the code parts might be relevant):

```
 function buildUploadBuffers(cmds, len, vertexUploadBuffer, matrixUploadBuffer)
       {
            var vertexOffset = 0;
            var matrixOffset = 0;

            var quadLen = 24; //96 bytes for each quads, /4 since we're stepping 4 bytes at a time
            var matLen = 16; //64/4, 4 rows of 4x floats with 4 bytes each, again stepping 4 bytes at a time

            for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                var cmd = cmds[i];
                var cmdQuads = cmd._numQuads;
                var source = cmd._quadU32View;
                var slen = cmdQuads * quadLen;

                vertexUploadBuffer.set(source,vertexOffset);
                vertexOffset += slen;

                var mat = cmd._stackMatrixMat;
                for(var j=0;j<cmdQuads * 4;++j)
                {
                    matrixUploadBuffer.set(mat, matrixOffset);
                    matrixOffset += matLen;
                }
            }
        }
```

It retrieves some typedArrays from each cmd in the cmds array and uses it to set values in some typedarray buffers.

This function is optimized fine, however, 'len' here is quite large and the data that is copied from the source typedArrays is quite small, and I have tested and profiled in the past that manually writing out the "set()"s can be significantly faster than relying on the compiler to optimize correctly. Further sometimes you can merge computations (such as here in the second loop because I copy the same thing 4 times to different places, but this is omitted in the following code since it doesn't change the results, for simplicity)

Doing this with the function above turns it into this:

```
function buildUploadBuffers(cmds, len, vertexUploadBuffer, matrixUploadBuffer)
        {
            var vertexOffset = 0;
            var matrixOffset = 0;

            var quadLen = 24; //96/4 since we're stepping 4 bytes at a time
            var matLen = 16; //64/4

            for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                var cmd = cmds[i];
                var cmdQuads = cmd._numQuads;
                var source = cmd._quadU32View;
                var slen = cmdQuads * quadLen;

                for(var j=0;j<slen; ++j)
                {
                    vertexUploadBuffer[vertexOffset + j] = source[j];
                }
                vertexOffset += slen;

                var mat = cmd._stackMatrixMat;
                for(var j=0;j<cmdQuads * 4;++j)
                {
                    for(var k=0;k<matLen; ++k)
                    {
                        matrixUploadBuffer[matrixOffset + k] = mat[k];
                    }
                    matrixOffset += matLen;
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this second function is not optimized ("optimized too many times") despite doing essentially the same thing.

Running v8 with deopt traces produces the following suspicious statements (these are repeated several times in the output, until finally the compiler says no thanks and stops optimizing):

> [compiling method 0000015F320E2B59 JS Function buildUploadBuffers
>   (SharedFunctionInfo 0000002ACC62A661) using Crankshaft OSR]
>
> [optimizing 0000015F320E2B59 JS Function buildUploadBuffers
>   (SharedFunctionInfo 0000002ACC62A661) - took 0.070, 0.385, 0.093 ms]
>
> [deoptimizing (DEOPT eager): begin 0000015F320E2B59 JS Function
>   buildUploadBuffers (SharedFunctionInfo 0000002ACC62A661) (opt #724)
>   @28, FP to SP delta: 280, caller sp: 0x2ea1efcb50]
>               ;;; deoptimize at 4437: Unknown map in polymorphic access

So it seems that the deoptimization fails because of polymorphic access somewhere. Needless to say, the types contained in cmds are not always the same. They can be one of two concrete types that share the same prototype one step up the chain ('base class') where all the queried attributes come from (numQuads, quadU32View etc.).

Further

- Why would it not just fail optimization with the first function that just uses .set() then? I'm accessing the same properties on the same objects. I'd think polymorphic access would break it in either case.
- Type info of the function seems to be fine? When optimizing it the debug output says

  > ICs with typeinfo: 23/23 (100%), generic ICs: 0/23 (0%)]
- Assuming there's nothing weird going on and the fact that the cmds can be one of two different types is indeed the culprit, how can I help out the optimizer here? The data in those cmds that I need from them is always the same, so there should be some way to package it up better for the optimizer, right? Maybe put a "quadData" object inside each cmd that contains numQuads, quadU32View, etc.? (just stabbing in the dark here)
- Something that's very weird: Commenting out either of the two inner loops (or both at the same time of course) leads to the function getting optimized again. Is the function getting too long for the optimizer or something?
- Because of the above point, I figured something might be weird with the (j) loop variable, so I tried using different ones for the different loops, which didn't change anything.

edit: Sure enough, the function optimizes again after I (e.g.) take out the second inner loop (uploading the matrix) and put it into a separate function. Interestingly enough this separate function is then seemingly inlined perfectly and I got the performance improvement I hoped for. Still makes me wonder what's going on here that prevents optimization. Just for completeness here's the thing that now optimizes well (and performs better, by about 25%):

```
function uploadMatrix(matrixUploadBuffer, mat, matLen, numVertices, matrixOffset)
        {
            for(var j=0;j<numVertices;++j)
            {
                for(var k=0;k<matLen; ++k)
                {
                    matrixUploadBuffer[matrixOffset + k] = mat[k];
                }
                matrixOffset += matLen;
            }

            return matrixOffset;
        }

        function buildUploadBuffers(cmds, len, vertexUploadBuffer, matrixUploadBuffer)
        {
            var vertexOffset = 0;
            var matrixOffset = 0;

            var quadLen = 24; //96/4 since we're stepping 4 bytes at a time
            var matLen = 16; //64/4

            for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                var cmd = cmds[i];
                var cmdQuads = cmd._numQuads;
                var source = cmd._quadU32View;
                var slen = cmdQuads * quadLen;

                for(var j=0;j<slen; ++j)
                {
                    vertexUploadBuffer[vertexOffset + j] = source[j];
                }
                vertexOffset += slen;

                var mat = cmd._stackMatrixMat;
                matrixOffset = uploadMatrix(matrixUploadBuffer,mat, matLen, cmdQuads *4, matrixOffset);
            }
        }
```